# If $P(x|y)$ is Gaussian, is $P(y|x)$ necessarily Gaussian?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $x$ and $y$ be two random variables. If
$P(x|y)$ is Gaussian, is $P(y|x)$ necessarily Gaussian?

I think it's not since
$$
P(y|x) = \frac{P(x|y)P(y)}{\int P(x|y)P(y)dy}.
$$

So unless $P(y)$ is Gaussian, $P(y|x)$ is not necessarily Gaussian.

Is the above argument correct?

Comment: Assuming that the conditional distribution is Gaussian, you can have something like P(height | gender ), gender  is obviously not Gaussian, neither marginally, nor conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, $Y$ can be any distribution.

Comment: What if $X = f(Y) + \xi$ where $f$ is a one-to-one deterministic function and $\xi$ is an independent Gaussian noise? Does it mean $P(Y|X)$ is Gaussian? I think it's still not based on the argument I gave in the OP.

Comment: @user3750444 - in your example then perhaps if $f$ is a linear function of $X$